# Parsing nethogs tracemode output

Tags: shell, networking

## Parsing nethogs

I am trying to parse the output of **nethogs -d 1 -t** to the following format:

```
5.65273 767.912
14.2687 1681.15
19.9011 2309.54
```

where the first (resp. second) column represents the *total* number of KB/s sent (resp. received) by my machine. Each line is a measurement taken at intervals of 1 seconds (the **-d** arg).

## My attempt until now

By running

```
sudo nethogs -d 1 -t
```

I get the following raw output

```
Adding local address: 192.168.0.23
Adding local address: fe80::cb1b:6973:f77f:34
Ethernet link detected
Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)

Refreshing:
unknown TCP/0/0 0   0

Refreshing:
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/12576/1000 4.07988 543.749
/opt/google/chrome/chrome/2441/1000 1.57285 224.163
unknown TCP/0/0 0   0

Refreshing:
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/12576/1000 11.9787 1330.22
/opt/google/chrome/chrome/2441/1000 2.26895 350.36
unknown TCP/0/0 0   0

Refreshing:
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/12576/1000 17.6111 1958.61
/opt/google/chrome/chrome/2441/1000 2.26895 350.36
unknown TCP/0/0 0   0
```

By running the command

```
sudo nethogs -d 1 -t 2>&1 | sed '1,5d;/Refreshing:/d;s_\t_ _g'
```

I am able to produce a cleaner output which ressembles

```
unknown TCP/0/0 0 0

/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/12576/1000 4.07988 543.749
/opt/google/chrome/chrome/2441/1000 1.57285 224.163
unknown TCP/0/0 0 0

/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/12576/1000 11.9787 1330.22
/opt/google/chrome/chrome/2441/1000 2.26895 350.36
unknown TCP/0/0 0 0

/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/12576/1000 17.6111 1958.61
/opt/google/chrome/chrome/2441/1000 2.26895 350.36
unknown TCP/0/0 0 0
```

Now how to I go from this to my desired output? I tried to use **awk**  to sum the outputs for one measurement like this

```
sudo nethogs -d 1 -t 2>&1 | sed '1,5d;/Refreshing:/d;s_\t_ _g' | awk 'BEGIN{sent=0; recv=0;};{if (NF >= 2) sent+=$(NF-1); recv+=$NF;}; END{print sent, recv;};'
```

but that does not produce any output. I could put the output of **sed** in a file and then apply **awk** to each paragraph but I feel like there is a more direct way to do it and one which would give me continuous output which I would prefer.

Comment: For us that do not have access to `nethogs`, what does the output that you are parsing look like?

Comment: @Kusalananda done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking the lines that start or don't start with a slash into account:

```
$ awk '/^[/]/ { sent+=$(NF-1); recv+=$NF }
       /^[^/]/ && sent>0 && recv>0 { print sent, recv; sent = recv = 0 }' file
5.65273 767.912
14.2477 1680.58
19.8801 2308.97
```

This just adds to `sent` and `recv` from lines that starts with a slash character. When encountering a line that doesn't start with a slash character, the current accumulated `sent` and `recv` values are outputted (and then reset to zero).  The output only happens if the variables contain a value greater than zero.